# Отследить POST запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, браузер

Есть сайт, который отправляет POST запрос на сервер методом ajax и мне нужно узнать на какой url отправляется запрос и какие параметры в нём передаються

Comment: Вам - Вам, или Вам - вашему скрипту на сайте?

Comment: Открываете панель разработчика в браузере на вкладке сеть и смотрите все запросы и их содержимое.

Comment: Чужой сайт отправляет с помощью ajax данный на свой сервер путём POST запроса и мне нужно узнать параметры которые он отправляет и url скрипта, который принимает эти данные

Comment: Я вам написал выше, что делать.